# GitHub Actions - ошибка Host key verification failed

Tags: github, github-actions

Всем привет!

Пытаюсь настроить автодеплои с GitHub на сервер по ssh. С локалки все работает отлично использовав `rsync`. Но когда пытаюсь собрать `deploy.yaml` на ГитХабе возникает ошибка `Host key verification failed`.

Кто может подсказать как можно исправить, или найти другие примеры деплоя через GitHub

Я думаю что ошибка на этапе `# Setup key` в скрипте.

**Вот сам скрипт**

```
name: DeployDev

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [12.x]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      # Setup key
      - run: set -eu
      - run: mkdir "$HOME/.ssh" #Создаю папку
      - run: echo "${{ secrets.key }}" >> "$HOME/.ssh/key" #Кладу туда свой id_rsa
      - run: chmod 600 "$HOME/.ssh/key" #Выдаю права
      # Deploy
      - run: cd wp-content/themes/m-shop
      - run: rsync "ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/key -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" -avzh --archive --compress . ${{ secrets.sshlink }}
```

**Вот скрин ошибки**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Что не помогло:**

1. Выполнил на сервере `ssh-keyscan -H github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts` - Не дало результата

Answer (score 0):

Сам нашел ошибку.

Все заключалось в неправильном пути к файлам id_rsa.
Исправив шаг `# Setup key` как показано в этом примере, все заработало.
Так же добавляю `ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts` - на всякий случай.

```
name: DeployDev

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [12.x]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      # Setup key
      - run: set -eu
      - run: mkdir -p ~/.ssh
      - run: echo "${{ secrets.KEY }}" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
      - run: chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
      - run: ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
      # Deploy
      - run: cd wp-content/themes/m-shop
      - run: rsync -e "ssh -i ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa/id_rsa -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" -avzh --archive --compress . ${{ secrets.sshlink }}
```